# Are there any approaches to measuring “physical”/“neurophysiological” aspects of one's intellectual tone/state of fluid intelligence?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, measurement, intelligence

Is it possible to measure/approximate/estimate intelligence with a physiological metric? What I mean is, if I put it correctly: to measure/estimate short-term memory capacity/long-term memory efficiency, speed of information transmission through brain cells/speed of new connections formation between cells etc.

For example, what can be deduced/assessed/assumed from the **electroencephalogram** results? Is there some activity pattern that may be related to forgetting or the like?

Comment: Hi Laffy, as you can see I made some major edits to your question. I did this to make your question clearer and less broad, which are reasons to close questions. I hope that I interpreted your question correctly. If you don't agree feel free to make additional changes.